# Error installing Azure java toolkit for Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, azure

I am trying to install the Azure Java toolkit with the help of this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/azure/hh690946.aspx

But now I am getting the following error:

```
    An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
    session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee,  phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
    Unable to read repository at http://dl.msopentech.com/eclipse/plugins/com.microsoft.sqljdbc4_4.0.2206.100.jar.
    Read timed out
```

I hope that someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears it was blocked by a firewall at work. I installed it at home.